# Minimum combinations of elements from multiple lists such that all elements appear at least once

Tags: python, algorithm, combinations

So the problem I have is this:

There are multiple groups, each containing multiple individuals along with a rank.
For example

```
GroupA = [('Joe', 1), ('Kate', 2), ('Jeff', 1)]
GroupB = [('Sam', 1), ('Jim', 2), ('Stephanie', 2)]
GroupCC = [('Adam', 2), ('David', 1), ('Liz', 1), ('Michael', 2)]
```

- I am assembling multiple teams containing exactly one person from each group, such that every team contains 3 people.
  ex. `['Kate', 'Sam',  'Adam']`
- One person can belong to multiple teams, but persons with rank 1 should have priority. If there are multiple people with rank 1, then it should be evenly distributed.

What is the minimum number of teams I can assemble such that every player belongs to a team?

In this case, the obvious answer is 4 teams, because listC has the most elements. That also means there will be an individual from listA and list B that will be included twice. I want to make sure that the person utilized twice is Joe or Jeff from listA, and Sam from list B.

Comment: Shouldn't the minimal number of teams always be the length of the longest list, given people can be assigned to multiple teams (no limit stated)?

Comment: Or is the problem here solely the assignment, because the only question I see is "What is the minimum number of teams I can assemble such that every player belongs to a team?"

Comment: I wasn't clear enough. I want to know what the combinations are as well. Just one random set is sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, lets generalize this to any number of groups

```
GroupA = [('Joe', 1), ('Kate', 2), ('Jeff', 1)]
GroupB = [('Sam', 1), ('Jim', 2), ('Stephanie', 2)]
GroupC = [('Adam', 2), ('David', 1), ('Liz', 1), ('Michael', 2)]
groups = [GroupA, GroupB, GroupC]
```

Then we'll iterate over the groups, and repeat elements as necessary (prioritizing 1's). We'll also strip the rank from each element in the list.

```
max_len = max(map(len, groups))

names = []
for group in groups:
    subgroup = list(group)
    if any(rank == 1 for _, rank in group):
        subgroup = list(filter(lambda x:x[1] == 1, group))
    group += subgroup * (max_len - len(group))
    names.append([name for name, _ in group])
```

Now names contains lists of names, with names repeated at least as many times as necessary to match the longest group (likely more, which `zip` will trim).

We'll know zip these lists together, and obtain our teams.

```
teams = list(zip(*names))
```

The result:

```
>>> print("\n".join(map(str, teams)))
('Joe', 'Sam', 'Adam')
('Kate', 'Jim', 'David')
('Jeff', 'Stephanie', 'Liz')
('Joe', 'Sam', 'Michael')
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks!